# prove that $\sup\{|p(z_1,z_2,z_3)|: |z_i|=1 , i=1,2,3\}<4$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z_1,z_2,z_3)=z_1z_2z_3-z_1^3-z_2^3-z_3^3$. Then 
prove that $\sup\{|p(z_1,z_2,z_3)|: |z_i|=1 , i=1,2,3\}<4$.

$|p(z_1,z_2,z_3)|\leq 1+|z_1^3+z_2^3+z_3^3|\leq 4$. I am not able to prove strictly less than 4.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for any non zero complex numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$, one has $$|a+b+c|=|a|+|b|+|c|$$ if and only if $b=\lambda a$ and $c=\mu a$ where $\lambda,\mu\geq 0$.

Hence $$1+|z_1^3+z_2^3+z_3^3| =4 \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}z_2^3& = & \lambda z_1^3 \\ z_3^3 & = & \mu z_1^3\end{array}\right. \text{ with } \lambda,\mu \geq 0$$
But $|z_k|=1$ thus $\lambda=\mu=1$ and $z_2$, $z_3$ can be written as $$z_2=\omega^k z_1, \ z_3=\omega^l z_1$$ where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity.

Therefor, if $|p(z_1,z_2,z_3)|=4$ then $z_2=\omega^k z_1$ and $z_3=\omega^l z_1$. However, one can check that : 
$$\begin{align*}
\left|p(z_1,\omega^kz_1,\omega^lz_1)\right| & =\left|\omega^{k+l}\cdot z_1^3-3z_1^3\right| \\
& = |z_1|^3\cdot \left|\omega^{k+l}-3\right| \\
& =\left|\exp\left(\dfrac{2i\pi (k+l)}{3}\right)-3\right| \neq 4\end{align*}$$
So for any $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ in the unit circle, $|p(z_1,z_2,z_3)|$ is strictly less than 4 and so is its maximum by compacity.